# What does "net off" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Credit risk adjustments are netted off balance exposures before
>   applying risk weighting.

In the above example, does "net off" mean to exclude? which means that "adjustments are excluded from balance exposure".

Comment: .....are netted, off balance exposures...

Comment: Then what does "net" mean in this context? Does it mean that "adjustments are calculated/recognized outside balance exposure"?

Comment: to net something would mean to take a net amount of something:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Questionable sentence**: Credit risk adjustments are netted off balance exposures before applying risk weighting.

This sounds totally unidiomatic because the word balance is used incorrectly. There is: **on-balance sheet exposure** and **off-balance sheet exposure** and plain old **balance sheet exposure**. In English, you don't "net something off of something".

Here is the lingo describing this for banking from the European Banking Authority: [credit risk adjustment](https://www.eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy/single-rulebook/interactive-single-rulebook/-/interactive-single-rulebook/article-id/949)

That said, I suppose they mean:
Credit risk adjustments are netted from balance exposures before applying risk weighting. 
Where: netted from means: t**aken as a net amount from balance exposures**.

But, **to tell you the truth, it is hard to say what they mean exactly**.

To net means: to calculate as a net amount.

Generally speaking, one has balance sheet exposure, not balance exposure.

I hope this helped.